# Organizar uma serie temporal

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Tenho uma base com informacoes coletadas de ganho de peso por animal. Elas foram coletadas em intervalos diferentes para cada animal. Segue parte da base logo abaixo

```html
Animal Dia Ganho
5 2 0.99
5 9 1.01
5 16 1.03
5 23 1.08
5 30 1.08
5 37 1.07
6 5 0.99
6 10 1.01
6 17 1.02
6 24 1.04
6 33 1.07
6 38 1.08
```

Primeiro preciso colocar em intervalos de um dia para cada animal. Segue um exemplo abaixo, pode ficar NA nos dias que nao tem informacao.

```html
Animal Dia Ganho
5 2 0.99
5 3 NA
5 4 NA
5 5 NA
5 6 NA
5 7 NA
5 8 NA
5 9 1.01
```

Por fim preciso remover somente os tres primeiros dias de cada animal da base.

Answer (score 3):

Utilizei os pacotes `dplyr` e `tidyr` para resolver o seu problema.

```
dados <- data.frame(
  Animal = c(rep(5,6), rep(6,6)), 
  Dia = c(2,9,16,23,30,37,5,10,17,24,33,38),
  Ganho = c(0.99,1.01,1.03,1.08,1.08,1.07,0.99,1.01,1.02,1.04,1.07,1.08)
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dados2 <- dados %>%
  group_by(Animal) %>% 
  complete(Dia = seq(from = min(Dia), to = max(Dia), by = 1), fill = list(Ganho = NA)) %>% 
  slice(4:n())
```